Why safari ask permision for allow popup on every window.open() after I changed my service worker?
Why safari ask permision for allow popup on every window.open() after I changed my service worker?and doesnot allow to open new tab.This is code of my service-worker.
After update my service worker, pwa apps installed in all my user devices now can open new link in my app and navigate because safari block new tap
import { clientsClaim } from "workbox-core";
import { ExpirationPlugin } from "workbox-expiration";
import { precacheAndRoute, createHandlerBoundToURL } from "workbox-precaching";
import { registerRoute } from "workbox-routing";
import { StaleWhileRevalidate } from "workbox-strategies";

clientsClaim();

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);

const fileExtensionRegexp = new RegExp("/[^/?]+\\.[^/]+$");
registerRoute(
  // Return false to exempt requests from being fulfilled by index.html.
  ({ request, url }) => {
    // If this isn't a navigation, skip.
    if (request.mode !== "navigate") {
      return false;
    } // If this is a URL that starts with /_, skip.

    if (url.pathname.startsWith("/_")) {
      return false;
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.

    if (url.pathname.startsWith("/api/")) {
      return false;
    } // If this looks like a URL for a resource, because it contains // a file extension, skip.

    if (url.pathname.match(fileExtensionRegexp)) {
      return false;
    } // Return true to signal that we want to use the handler.

    return true;
  },
  createHandlerBoundToURL(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/index.html")
);

// An example runtime caching route for requests that aren't handled by the
// precache, in this case same-origin .png requests like those from in public/
registerRoute(
  // Add in any other file extensions or routing criteria as needed.
  ({ url }) =>
    url.origin === self.location.origin &&
    [".png", ".webp", ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpg"].some(char => url.pathname.endsWith(char)), // Customize this strategy as needed, e.g., by changing to CacheFirst.
  new StaleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: "images",
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({ maxEntries: 50 })
    ]
  })
);

self.addEventListener("message", function (event) {
  if (
    ["https://example.com", "https://preprod-example.com", "https://qc-example.com"].indexOf(
      event.origin
    ) !== -1 &&
    event.data &&
    event.data.type === "SKIP_WAITING"
  ) {
    self.skipWaiting();
  } else return;
});

self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
  if (event.request.url.match("^.*(/api/).*$")) {
    return false;
  }
  if (event.request.url.indexOf("/api/") !== -1) {
    return false;
  }

  if (event.request.url.includes("/api/")) {
    return;`your text`
  }
  
  event.respondWith(fetch(event.request));
});


The reason of ask popup permission for every new tab was related to call window.open() asynchronously after update my service worker, and after call it outside of asynchronously function worked well.
